# Communication between RPi and Arduino via UART

Tags: python

I am making my Arduino to communicate with RPi via Serial communication. When RPi send '1' to Arduino, the Arduino will reply with data from sensors. The communication works but when it comes to classifying the received data, there's something weird going on...

```
Step 1: From RPi to Arduino. The message '1'
Step 2: Arduino acknowledged, then from Arduino to RPi, the message is '[0.10,8.0,1]'
Step 3: RPi split the received message into 3 data (since it's from 3 sensors) - Problem's at here
```

Here's the full coding:

```
import serial

ser=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

newData = False
receivedChar = ""
recvInProgress = False
data_0 = 0
data_1 =0
data_2 = 0

def recvWithStartEndMarkers():
    global newData
    global receivedChar
    global recvInProgress

    startMarker = '['
    endMarker = ']'

    while ser.inWaiting() > 0 and newData == False:
        rc = ser.read(1)
        rc = rc.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')

        if recvInProgress == True:
            if rc != endMarker:
               receivedChar += rc
            else:
               recvInProgress = False

        elif rc = startMarker:
            recvInProgress = True

def showNewData():
    global newData

    if newData == True:
        print(receivedChar) #The outcome at the console is "0.10,8.0,1" , which is what I want.
        newData = False

def Process_Recv_Data():
    global data_0
    global data_1
    global data_2

    if receivedChar != "":
        data = receivedChar.split(',')

        # PROBLEM IS AT HERE
        for each_data in data:
            print(each_data) 
        #At the console, I am seeing this:
        #0
        #.
        #1
        #0
        # 
        #
        #8
        #.
        #0
        #
        #
        #1

        receivedChar = ""

cmd = '1'
ser.write(cmd.encode())

while True:
    recvWithStartEndMarkers()
    showNewData()
    Process_Recv_Data()
```

So, end up I can't put 0.10 into data_0, 8.0 into data_1 and 1 into data_2. Why is this happening?

*ps, I know my coding is quite messy and shouldn't be using that many of global variable. I will tidy up later so please don't command on this. Thank you.*

Comment: Can you include the output of `print recievedChar` before performing `split(',')` as a comment.?

Comment: I strongly suggest you passing data as argument (in python thing like) `return a,b,c` is lecit, so you avoid having overlapping names (that most probably are causiing your issues)

Comment: #0
        #.
        #1
        #"0"
        # 
        #
        #8
        #.
        #0
        #
        #
        #1

Comment: @AshSharma wow, why is this happening? I am confused...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AshSharma for inspiring me on where's the problem. The problem is that, before the whole data is COMPLETELY RECEIVED, I am performing the splitting. Here's the solution:

```
def showNewData():
    global newData
    global receivedChar

    if newData == True:
        data = receivedChar.split(",")
        print(data)
        newData = False

#No need for def Process_Recv_Data() anymore
```

This is kind of a silly mistake. *Facepalm